# Should segments with identical source and target be omitted from training data?

Tags: training-data, microsoft-translator

I'm training a Japanese -> English system in Custom Translator and am wondering if segments in training data in which the source and target are identical should be taken out before upload. 
An example would be a segment in which both source and target are something like "5000 km". These occur quite a bit in our data.
Does having too many of these segments affect quality or does it not make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, training machine translation what *not* to translate is very important.  So the effect should be positive or neutral, assuming the examples are correct.

Ideally you include minimal pairs, so you also have examples of similar inputs that should get translated, not just copied.

In the case of `5000km`, it may be removed anyway because the length filter removes anything that's only a single word.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/data-filtering#length-filter

> #### Length
>
> - Remove sentences with only one word on either side.
>     ...

I don't want to say that it is definitely removed, because the underlying implementation may be tokenising it into two words (`5000` and `km`).

Moreover, anything that is already in the target language script - the Latin alphabet in this case - is probably not going to get translated anyway by the generic model.

There may be more impact if such tokens are included in full sentences where parts of the sentence do get translated.